bug with beamer and lastpage?
I think I may have found a bug with beamer and lastpage at least on my mac with the 2024 distribution. This code, which has always compiled, does not now
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\begin{document}
document
\end{document}

giving
enddocument/afterlastpage: lastpage setting LastPage.
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...Hy@unicodefalse \Hy@PageAnchorSlide
                                                  \pdfstringdef \@the@H@page...
l.5 \end{document}

Was just wondering if there is a workaround, and what might the best way to report this?
best Jack

hm, I get an error but a different one. Is your system up-to-date?

I get ! Argument of \lastpage@currentH has an extra }., TL2024 updated some 12 hours ago.

My system is the 2024 mactex distribution, but the error message is much longer, so I probably show a different part of it. That said, I see you confirm it is a bug so its not me missing something obvious.

no there is clearly a problem and I will report it to beamer. But I do not know if a solution will resolve your problem as you get a different error. Check your version of lastpage. It should be version 2024/04/27 v2.1a lastpage.

Thanks Ulrike! I am solving by using last year's mactex distribution, so not a huge burden to me at least, but of course, would be great to get fixed.

I opened a beamer issue https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/903 and also wrote the lastpage maintainer, the package shouldn't rely on @currentHpage being not empty.

Excellent Ulrike. Thanks for that, and have a wonderful day.

Instead of lastpage, you could use beamer's own macros to insert the number of the last page/frame/etc.
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\inserttotalframenumber 

\insertpresentationendpage

\insertappendixendpage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=none] 
\end{frame}

\end{document}


thanks! I knew the \inserttotalframenumber  but did not know about \insertpresentationendpage which indeed solves the problem. Should have searched better.  I have some pages that are not frames, like the one with \printbibliography[heading=none] since else it overflows the frame,

@jackstrauss Don't use pages without frames. Instead you can use the allowframebreaks option to allow the bibliography to split across multiple slides.

Wow, I have used beamer for years and for 1000s of slides, and never thought to look for that. Even better. excellent.

@jackstrauss Too bad beamer didn't break lastpage earlier so you would have asked a question years ago :)

indeed, many of my regular latex documents use lastpage and I just blindly copied it to beamer, now for over 5 years! Just does to show one can always learn more latex.

Beamer loaded part of hyperref, and then lastpage thought that hyperref had been loaded completely. This has been fixed since version 2.1b 2024-07-03 of the lastpage package.
